# Max Columns(20+) in Table - SAP UI5

Tags: sapui5, responsive

SAP Fiori suggests to go for Responsive Table `sap.m.Table`. But some time the requirement comes like table having 20+ columns in a table .

At this time, what I need to use(especially for this scenario). Either `sap.ui.table` or `sap.m.table`

Answer (score 2):

according to the [Fiori-guidelines](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/table-overview/) `sap.ui.table` should be used when you are using large data sets, if not `sap.m.table`is recommended.

The biggest disadvantage of `sap.ui.table` is that it isn't completely responsive. Then again if you are talking about 20+ columns, I might assume that you don't need it to be responsive.

I don't know with what amount of data you are working, but I think `sap.ui.table` will be a better pick for you in this scenario

Comment: I have limited number of rows(less than 50). But the number of columns are 25 in a table. If this is a case, should i go with sap.ui.table?.

Comment: @karthikstj based on the info you provided here I would say yes, It might be intresting if you check following checklist before making your final choice: https://a.kabachnik.info/sap.m.table-vs-sap.ui.table.table-features-compared.html

Comment: Good info. Thanks.